# Please Don't Flag This Question

Tags: knowledge, visual, geography, connect-wall, flags

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42: Wordless Connecting Walls](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7045/fortnightly-topic-challenge-42-wordless-connecting-walls)</sup>

---

Today, I received a rather *peculiar* mail from L.B.G. (Low-Budget Gladys), Glady's cousin, thrice removed (and aunt to the daughter of knock-off Gladys)...

> Heya, North! So, a couple of weeks back, I went to go watch a WONDERFUL virtual concert- oh! it was just fantastic! Granted, some of the locations [needs improvement], but it was generally amazing because I could go anywhere without leaving my couch! Leave it to my some distant cousin to *actually* go to places. Always [spam[sic]] me with those puzzles. But instead of being [rude and abusive] to my cousin, I figured, I'll just [duplicate] what she does!
> Lovingly Yours, L.B.G.

[image]

I have... no clue what she's talking about, but can you help me figure out where she went?

Overdue hint #1 updated:

> One of the categories has to do with dogs. Think herding dogs.

Hint #2 (slightly updated):

> One of the categories has to do very specifically with the flag itself.

Hint #3:

> The Wikipedia page for Switzerland isn't loading properly for some reason. It's in the same category as [Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil) and [China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China). And [Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey).

Comment: Is the text important to the puzzle?

Comment: No. It's just flavortext

Comment: Quick hint, to get people started: this country (the answer) was inspired by one of my pets :P

Comment: unfortunately I doubt anyone here besides you knows about your pets

Comment: @merrybot The claim that it is inspired by *a* pet is already a hint, although I don't know how to use it ..

Comment: My hunch is something to do with ginuea pigs?

Comment: @PrinceNorthLæraðr has the size of the flags something to do with a group?, because I am having a suspicion there.

Comment: @Anonymous Definitely on the right track

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The flags, from left to right and top to bottom:

> England, Brazil, Germany, North Korea
>  Mongolia, Rwanda, Netherlands, Switzerland 
>  Mozambique, Hungary, Turkey, Picardie (historical region of France) 
>  Papua New Guinea, Ghana, Latvia, China

Group #1:

> **[Members of the Commonwealth of Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Commonwealth_of_Nations_countries_by_GDP_(nominal))**
>  Ghana, Papua New Guinea, Mozambique, Rwanda

Group #2:

> **Countries whose capital is not their largest city**
>  Brazil (Brasilia), Switzerland (de facto Bern), China (Beijing), Turkey (Ankara)

Group #3:

> **Countries with breeds of herding dogs ending in "Shepherd" named after them**
>  Picardy (Picardy Shepherd), Netherlands (Dutch Shepherd), England (English Shepherd), Germany (German Shepherd)

Group #4:

> **Countries with 1:2 ratio flags**
>  Mongolia, North Korea, Latvia, Hungary

Where did L.B.G. go?

> Somewhere that is a member of the Commonwealth of Nations, whose capital is not its largest city, has a 1:2 ratio flag, and has a species of herding dog named after it.

> **Australia**
>  [image]

Comment: Quick modification of Group 4: All members of group 4 have a flag ratio of 1:2. It was very specific. Otherwise, nice job! I have an Australian Sheperd, hence the original comment hint.

Comment: Ah, well done.\! I was looking at shepherd breeds too, but got tripped up on the third hint, since I'd sorted Swiss Shepherds in there.